# Ways to communicate between JScript and Windows service

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, wsh, jscript

I have a Windows local service that may spawn off a process to execute a JScript script (in a .js file) via the Windows Script Host. The issue is that I need to notify my service of the results generated by the script in the .js file. A transfer or a simple 32-bit integer, or a string would suffice. What would be the way to do this?

PS. The code must run on Windows XP SP3 or later OS.

Comment: @Deanna: I will definitely do that. I'm still working on it though. In the meantime I'm mulling over another possibility -- using system registry to pass the data. What do you think?

Comment: It's silly. There are many better methods of IPC rather than writing it to a permanent location on disk (even if for a short while).

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to create an out of process COM object that executes within your service. Just implement the necessary scripting interfaces and provide a member function to match the notification and call it from your script as such:

```
newObj = new ActiveXObject("localserver.mynotify");
newObj.Notify("finished");
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any C++ code samples to show how to add COM support into a service?

Comment: Don't think that `x = new Y(); x.f();` is valid C++.

Comment: @DeadMG It's not valid C++, it's valid Javascript.

Comment: @ahmd0 Sorry I don't have any offhand but if I come across any during my normal day I'll slap em up here

Answer (score 2):

Would the exit code of the process be enough?

Windows Scripting host has has a [`.Quit(errorCode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0fx1aw.aspx) method that allows you to set the exit code.
You should be able to call WSH directly from the service and get the return code with `GetProcessExitCode()` by passing the process handle that you received after spawning it.

Note that almost everything you can do from a JScript file can also be done with native code.

Comment: Good idea. But how do you return an exit code from a JScript file?

Comment: @ahmd0: Which is it? It's not clear from your qustion whether you're asking about getting the results from your JScript to the spawned process or from the spawned process to your service. My answer (and Caption Oblivious's) is for the latter.

Comment: Deanna, the question of whether or not the use of JScript is needed or why it must be in a separate process is not the point of this question. Your initial idea to use return code seems very good, but then you contradicted yourself by saying that it's not available. So, yes, the goal is to communicate the result from a JScript file to a local service. So the use of COM is appropriate, I just need to figure out how to incorporate COM into my C++ service. My other idea was to use the System Registry but I'm not sure if I can write into it from JScript. (Note, not JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to execute the .js file as an external process?  Windows Scripting has COM objects that an app can use to run scripts within its own process.  I use this to execute script files within my service processes, and it works fine.  The hosting process can even implement its own `IDispatch`-based classes and pass them to the scripting engine to expose to scripts as global objects so the scripts can communicate with the hosting process without having to use `new ActiveXObject` or `CreateObject()` to access those objects.

Comment: Thanks for this addition. No, I don't have to execute .js in an external process. It would be nice though if you could point me to a code sample (I code in C++) of how to run a .js script via a COM from a service?

Comment: Read up on MSDN about `IActiveScript` and its related interfaces. [Here is a good article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14905/COM-in-plain-C-Part-6),  though it is written for C (just ignore the VTBL portions, since C++ handles that for you). [Here is a shorter article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349554/Cplusplus-Win32-and-Scripting-Quick-way-to-add-Scr) that is written for for C++.

Answer (score 0):

I see your script is written in JScript and your app in C++.

Perhaps the easiest way to accomplish what you want is by writing a file, say, to programdata folder which your service should have access to. Maybe use a GUID for the particular request, pass that to the JScript so it's guaranteed to be a unique file. Not ideal.

Another way to get JScript output ... Can you call out to managed code (C#)? If so, you could use a .NET-based or .NET-callable JavaScript compiler/interpreter. This would allow you to avoid IActiveScript and also to grab the values right out of the script context or from function return. I've used [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com) and [JavaScriptDotNet](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/), both very easy to use and extend.

This might open a problem if you heavily rely on ActiveXObject calls (ie: FileSystemObject) and don't want to write components. [JuraScript](http://jurascript.codeplex.com) wraps the Jurassic engine and add ActiveXObject support to it for COM automation.

I am a C++ newb, so I don't know how much of a leap this is for you although I know it's possible to interop between managed/C++.

Just thought I'd mention these scenarios as I didn't see them listed in answers.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. And, no, I can't use any .NET-based stuff. The easiest way for me was to use HKCU registry hive to write from JavaScript and then read it from C++: var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); wsh.RegWrite(strKeyName, vValue, "REG_SZ");

Comment: Well, I'm with everyone else who says that's a baaaaad idea and poor practice, but as a fellow dev... sometimes you just need it to work.